# Using Crashlytics to send custom reports?

Tags: android, crashlytics, crashlytics-android, crashlytics-beta

Currently I can only send crash reports to Fabric Crashlytics and according to this [documentation](https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/enhanced-reports.html), I can attach custom messages and name-value pairs to **crash reports** using the following code:

```
Crashlytics.log("Error Passing Data for User: " + user.getId());
```

But this only gets triggered if a crash occurs and then this data will be attached to the report.

But is it possible to send a a custom report without waiting for a crash to trigger it? Pretty much using Fabric Crashlytics as an analytics service.

For example if I want to send a message to the dashboard saying a specific method could not be called or if certain data is missing. I am trying to use it for analytics purposes for the developers to track the internal process logs.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry it is not possible with Crashlytics. If you want to do Analytics try to use google analytics or FCM analytics. If you still want to do this thing with CrashReporting you can use FCM crash reporting where you can do this thing which you want. But with Crashlytics it is not possible.

Comment: I see. I will look in to GA and Firebase to implement this then. Thanks for the response, Andy! @AndyDeveloper

Comment: Welcome Sir :) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fabric provides an analytics module called [answers](https://docs.fabric.io/android/answers/overview.html).

It let you track events inside your app.
There are some predefined events but its also possible to  [define
your own events with custom attributes](https://docs.fabric.io/android/answers/answers-events.html#custom-event) like this:

```
Answers.getInstance().logCustom(
      new CustomEvent("Error")
          .putCustomAttribute("Error Passing Data for User", user.getId())
);
```

Tracked events are available nearly immediately and can be analyzed inside the webinterface of fabric.

Comment: Take into account that these attributes only partially appearing in the webinterface (even by hovering by mouse), and currently cannot be downloaded

Comment: For new visitors, this is deprecated and cannot publish your app with Fabric